# make a lineup optimizer for Football in compliance with the requirements

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a date frame with players, and a code that prints out the lineup for me, but the criteria is very narrow, and it only prints out once. I'm new to this, so I'm asking for help. I need him to display such 10 squads for me, plus so that I can specify which players to display with, and which ones not to select. Well, there can be a maximum of 2 defenders from one team, and the goalkeeper must be from another team too

```
# Helper variables
POS = df1.Position.unique()
CLUBS = df1.Club.unique()
BUDGET = 110
pos_available = {
    'defender': 4,
    'midfielder': 3,
    'forward': 3,
    'goalkeeper': 1,
}


# Initialize Variables
names = [df1.Name[i] for i in df1.index]
teams = [df1.Club[i] for i in df1.index]
positions = [df1.Position[i] for i in df1.index]
prices = [df1.Price[i] for i in df1.index]
points = [df1.EV[i] for i in df1.index]
players = [LpVariable("player_" + str(i), cat="Binary") for i in df1.index]

# Initialize the problem
prob = LpProblem("Choices", LpMaximize)

# Define the objective
prob += lpSum(players[i] * points[i] for i in range(len(df1))) # Objective

# Build the constraints
prob += lpSum(players[i] * df1.Price[df1.index[i]] for i in range(len(df1))) <= BUDGET # Budget Limit

for club in CLUBS:
  prob += lpSum(players[i] for i in range(len(df1)) if teams[i] == club) <= 3 # Club Limit
    
for pos in POS:
  prob += lpSum(players[i] for i in range(len(df1)) if positions[i] == pos) <= pos_available[pos] # Position Limit


# Solve the problem
prob.solve()

for v in prob.variables():
  if v.varValue != 0:
    name = df1.Name[int(v.name.split("_")[1])]
    club = df1.Club[int(v.name.split("_")[1])]
    position = df1.Position[int(v.name.split("_")[1])]
    point = df1.EV[int(v.name.split("_")[1])]
    price = df1.Price[int(v.name.split("_")[1])]
    print(name, position, club, point, price, sep=" - ")
```